# Is ~'' really the best way to pass a null parameter to a LESS mixin?

Tags: less

I am creating a series of mixins for LESS css where I use a mixin like this with media queries:

```
.animal(@color: ~'', @imgWidth: ~'') 
{
    & when not (@color = ~'')
    {
        color: @color;
    }

    & when not (@imageMargin = ~'')
    {
       img
       {
          width: @imgWidth;
       }
    }
}
```

As you can see the parameters default to `~''` and then I only output the property if a real value is passed in. This allows me to 'inherit' from the previous media query when nothing is passed in :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 20em) 
{
   .cat(@color: red, @imgWidth: 3em);
   .tiger(@color: blue, @imgWidth: 5em);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 20em) 
{
   .cat(@imgWidth: 5em);
   .tiger(@imgWidth: 7em);
}
```

The color doesn't need to be re-set for the second media query, only the @imgWidth parameter. So in the output CSS it isn't included.

This works fine, but its very cumbersome. It this really the only way to do optional parameters that should be ignored if not provided. Why does LESS even output parameters when they're empty? Is there a setting to disable this?

Comment: In your examples the actual default value does not really matter so it can be anything but the meaningful CSS value (e.g. `null`, `undefined`, `whatever`, `foobarbaz` etc.).

Comment: but then I get that all over my css. it's gzipped so it doesn't really matter but I'm just amazed there doesn't seem to be another way than explicitly writing a `when` for every property. plus when the person whose css I am premptively improving looks at mine I want it to look nice :-)

Comment: i'm wondering just leaving it as `''` and then running though some minifier that optimizes the empty values away

Comment: Well, these values are not supposed to get into CSS (unless you really need `color: ;` or `color; ''` there) so it does not matter how long they are.

Comment: it's just so ugly in the chrome inspector though :-( I think I'll stick with my `when`s since right now I don't have that many

Comment: Speaking of "explicitly writing a `when` for every property" - indeed, the more compact way to write your example is to simply specify each property directly [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/11276538#file-23282584-1-less). Also, after all, all these conditionals can be rewritten to be as compact as "one line per property" [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/11277015#file-23282584-2-less). Aside from above I recall related discussion [there](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1894) and I guess it has some additional food for thought.